# Logstash multiline filter in a single event when nested values are involved

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

My application logs the following intermittently in the logs

I want to create a kibana graph of these values continously. On careful monitoring we can know that it is nested

A mem has 3 values (a) size (b) free (c) largest

same way for B mem and c mem.

Please guide on how the logstash filter should be written.

LOG(09:44:26):: A Mem: Size: 491520 Free: 45320 Largest: 39484

LOG(09:44:26):: B Mem: Size: 3893248 Free: 1436928 Largest: 1392764

LOG(09:44:26)::C Mem: Size: 15544316 Free: 2080224 Largest: 2050012

LOG(09:44:28):: A Mem: Size: 491520 Free: 45325 Largest: 39480

LOG(09:44:28):: B Mem: Size: 3893248 Free: 1436920 Largest: 1392760

LOG(09:44:28)::C Mem: Size: 15544316 Free: 2080220 Largest: 2050015

Comment: LOG(09:44:26):: A Mem: Size: 491520 Free: 45320 Largest: 39484
LOG(09:44:26):: B Mem: Size: 3893248 Free: 1436928 Largest: 1392764
LOG(09:44:26)::C Mem: Size: 15544316 Free: 2080224 Largest: 2050012   \n                                                                                                                               LOG(09:44:28):: A Mem: Size: 491525 Free: 45320 Largest: 39483
LOG(09:44:28):: B Mem: Size: 3893240 Free: 1436926 Largest: 1392769
LOG(09:44:28)::C Mem: Size: 15544313 Free: 2080225 Largest: 2050010

Answer (score 0):

Writing a grok pattern which will pull that information out of the log lines you have provided as examples is relatively easy:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "LOG\(%{TIME}\)::\ %{WORD}\ Mem:\ Size:\ %{INT:Size}\ Free:\ %{INT:Free}\ Largest:\ %{INT:Largest}" }
}
```

However, I think you are looking to the wrong tool to graph this information, I don't think kibana will be able to graph these as you want, you will probably need to use graphite.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it is nested".

Comment: The above suggesstion will only work for a single line of input. I have created a grok already for that   'code' A Mem: Size: %{NUMBER:A_Mem_Size} Free: %{NUMBER:A_Free_Size} Largest: %{NUMBER:A_Largest_Size} 'code'. However there are 2 scenarios here. (a) the 3 lines are a single event, which mean A, B and C needed to be made a single event by multiline.  (b) It is nested, the structure is A_mem_size, A_mem_free, A_mem_largest. it is nested inside a_mem. Similarly for b_mem and c_mem

Comment: The answer I have given will work for the examples you have provided, without examples I won't be able to answer you question any better than I already have, rewriting the filter I have provided to match both those situations is trivial, but you need to configure the multiline filter to get your multiline examples in one line first, then make sure the patten works for both, or write 2 different grok match patterns for the 2 different situations.

Comment: example is : sample log file of my application within a time of 5 minutes:

Comment: I can't tell where the line breaks are, can you put it in your question instead?

Comment: sorry, but I am not sure how to put line breaks, a easy way would be to check the time. First event time is 09:44:26 while second event time is 09:44:28

Comment: first event   LOG(09:44:26):: A Mem: Size: 491520 Free: 45320 Largest: 39484
LOG(09:44:26):: B Mem: Size: 3893248 Free: 1436928 Largest: 1392764
LOG(09:44:26)::C Mem: Size: 15544316 Free: 2080224 Largest: 2050012

Comment: second event LOG(09:44:28):: A Mem: Size: 491525 Free: 45320 Largest: 39483
LOG(09:44:28):: B Mem: Size: 3893240 Free: 1436926 Largest: 1392769
LOG(09:44:28)::C Mem: Size: 15544313 Free: 2080225 Largest: 2050010

Comment: Rewriting the pattern I posted before to match these long lines is trivial as I said before. I'm not going to do it for you. I suggest you open another question or read the documentation if you don't understand how to use the multiline filter

Comment: I went through the multiline filter in logstash yesterday, but since all my 3 lines had the timestamp in them , I was not sure whether it could still be combined to one. I already have written the grok filter for one line and it is A Mem: Size: %{NUMBER:A_Mem_Size} Free: %{NUMBER:A_Free_Size} Largest: %{NUMBER:A_Largest_Size}.

Comment: Without some way to differentiate the log lines you want to bring together on one line from those you don't you wouldn't be able to use the multiline filter. I think you need to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok thank you. I am looking at possible ways by which this can be solved.